# Scaling an application on a client by client basis?

Tags: web-applications, scalability

I want to know what the general approach is to providing scalability on a client by client basis in a web application. For example, say I have a web application that I sell to clients, but I decide that having all of my clients on one instance of the application is just not scalable.

Is there something I can do about this? Can I have a way to "Spin up" a new instance for each client? Or maybe have it so that I can have multi-tenant instances for the clients with smaller budgets, but dedicated instances for the bigger clients with more money to spend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Slippy, usually you put a set of clients into a single instance of application and launch a new one when required. But if you want, you can run a separate instance of application for each user. Have a look at Docker that provides isolation of instances. If you want to run each instance at separate server you need to have a hosting that allows you to add new machines via API (like DigitalOcean, for example: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-the-digitalocean-api-v2).

Comment: Can I use docker, with AWS?